# Set UITableViewCell style programmatically in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I know you can set the style in `iOS Designer` but how would one do that in code?

Normally you request the cell with this function

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
```

I saw Objective-C solutions which created a new cell. After new paradigma you don't need to create a new cell if you use `RegisterClassForCellReuse`.

Is this the only way to set the style in code?

```
if (cell == null) {
    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14825/dequeuereusablecell-with-style):

> if you use RegisterClassForCellReuse, I think you have to use a custom cell that subclasses UITableViewCell. Otherwise it create a standard Cell with style Default.

The following works by registering the class in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(SubtitleTableViewCell), new NSString("SessionCell"));
```

And subclassing `UITableViewCell`. The `[Export]` attribute is required:

```
public class SubtitleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    [Export("initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:")]
    public SubtitleTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, string cellId)
        : base( UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellId) { }
}
```